# Parallel between the 12 tribes of Israel and the 12 princes of Ishmael?

Tags: shevatim-12-tribes, yishmael, asereth-hashvatim-ten-tribes, princes-of-tribes

Genesis 35:22

> ויהי בשכן ישראל בארץ ההוא וילך ראובן וישכב את בלהה פילגש אביו וישמע
> ישראל ויהיו בני יעקב שנים עשר
>
> And it came to pass, while Israel dwelt in that land, that Reuben went
> and lay with Bilhah his father's concubine; and Israel heard of it.
> {P} Now the **sons of Jacob were twelve**

Numbers 1:44

> אלה הפקדים אשר פקד משה ואהרן ונשיאי ישראל שנים עשר איש איש אחד לבית
> אבתיו היו
>
> These are those that were numbered, which Moses and Aaron numbered,
> and **the princes of Israel, being twelve men**; they were each one for
> his fathers' house.

Genesis 17:20

> ולישמעאל שמעתיך הנה ברכתי אתו והפריתי אתו והרביתי אתו במאד מאד שנים עשר נשיאם יוליד ונתתיו לגוי גדול
>
> And as **for Ishmael**, I have heard thee; behold, I have blessed him, and
> will make him fruitful, and will multiply him exceedingly; **twelve
> princes shall he beget**, and I will make him a great nation.

Genesis 25:16

> אלה הם בני ישמעאל ואלה שמתם בחצריהם ובטירתם שנים עשר נשיאם לאמתם
>
> these are **the sons of Ishmael**, and these are their names, by their
> villages, and by their encampments; **twelve princes according to their
> nations.**

Are there any traditional Rabbinic sources that discuss and draw a parallel between the twelve sons/princes of Ishmael and the twelve sons/princes/tribes of Israel? Preference given to sources in Hazal.

Comment: I think I've seen a connection between the 12 tribes and the 12 sons of Nachor

Comment: דְּתַנְיָא, אָמַר רִבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן, אִלְמָלֵא לָא אַקְרִיבוּ אִלֵּין תְּרֵיסָר נְשִׂיאִין, לָא יָכִיל עָלְמָא לְמֵיקָם קַמֵּי תְּרֵיסָר נְשִׂיאֵי יִשְׁמָעֵאל, דִּכְתִּיב, (בראשית כ״ה:ט״ז) שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר נְשִׂיאִים לְאוּמוֹתָם. מִדְּאַקְרִיבוּ אִלֵּין דְּיִשְׂרָאֵל, נָסִיבוּ שׁוּלְטָנוּתָא דְּכֻלְּהוּ, בְּגִין כָּךְ נָשִׂיא אֶחָד לַיּוֹם - זוהר, פרשת נשא

Comment: @user123 here's a translation, you can use it to formulate an answer: "We have learned that R. Shim'on said: If these twelve princes would not have brought their offerings, the world could not have prevailed before the twelve princes of Ishmael, as it is written: "Twelve princes according to their nations" (Gen. 25:16). When those twelve princes of Israel had brought their offerings, the dominion was taken away from all of them. Therefore, it is written: "Each prince on his day.""